# C# Class Object JavaScript like use

Tags: c#, class, object

In C# I have a class object defined like:

```
public class Row
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string full_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
```

Next I can use it like:

```
Row row = new Row();
```

And then do something like this to set a value:

```
row.id = "id123";
```

How do I make some type of "dynamic" reference? This doesn't work:

```
string col = "id";  
row[col] = "id123";
```

Comment: by using a `Dictionary<string, whatever>` for example.

Comment: @RoadRunner: This is just a snippet. This is part of  a much larger class library where I need to traverse over many SQL table columns of many tables. If I already have columns defined in my object I can use the `.Name` and `.PropertyType` of the definition in a foreach loop. Very open to other ways; just stuck with something simple here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Reflection in C# like this:

```
var prop=row.GetType().GetProperty("id");
prop.SetValue(row,"id123");
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your exact question, you could create a custom indexer:

```
public object this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        switch(key)
        {
             case nameof(id): return id;
             case nameof(full_name): return full_name;
             case nameof(email): return email;
             default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }      
    set
    {
        switch(key)
        {
             case nameof(id):
                 id = value.ToString();
                 break;
             case nameof(full_name):
                 full_name = value.ToString();
                 break;
             case nameof(email):
                 email = value.ToString();
                 break;
             default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}

public void Foo()
{
    var row = new Row();
    row["id"] = "Foo";
}
```

Or you [use reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55495066/2441442) as TSungur has answered:

```
public object this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        var prop = GetType().GetProperty(key);
        return prop.GetValue(this);
    }      
    set
    {
        var prop = GetType().GetProperty(key);
        prop.SetValue(this, value);
    }
}
```

However, If I were you, I would review your current library design. Probably you want to use an ORM like [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/), which does all the mapping for you.

Answer (score 1):

C# is a [strongly typed language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/). This means that once a type is defined, you can't changed it dynamically during run time*. You also can't access the properties of an object with [] like in JavaScript. Therefore you can't achieve what you are looking for in C#. C# way would most likely be to access the id property directly through `row.id = "id23";`. In C# you always know during compile time what properties and methods are available on an object. If you need more flexibility what properties will be there, you can also use a `Dictionary`, `KeyValuePair` or simply a `List`.

*There is actually a dynamic key word that gives you some of that functionality - but it's uncommon to use that all over the place. Coming from JavaScript I would recommend to forget about it for the moment. There is almost always an other, "more C#-like" way.